# What's the difference between normalize image to float 0~1, float -1~1, and integer 0~255 before feed into CNN?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

Whats the difference between normalize image to int and float?

1. Normalize to `[0, 255]`

```
   cv2.noramlize(src, res, 255, 0, cv2.NORM_MINMAX)
```

2. Normalize to `[0, 1]`

```
   cv2.normalize(src, res, 1, 0, cv2.NORM_MINMAX)
```

3. Normalize to `[-1, 1]`

```
   img=(img-np.mean(img, axis=(0,1)))/np.std(img, axis=(0,1))
```

Ps.
`img` is a image with `[H x W x C]`

Does it make any difference in training and performance of a ConvNet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
img=(img-np.mean(img, axis=(0,1)))/np.std(img, axis=(0,1))
```

The above piece of code does Mean Subtraction followed by Normalization.

you can refer to [CS231 Notes](http://cs231n.github.io/neural-networks-2/#datapre) for additional details, but here are the relevant portions

**Mean subtraction** is the most common form of preprocessing. It involves subtracting the mean across every individual feature in the data, and has the geometric interpretation of centering the cloud of data around the origin along every dimension. In numpy, this operation would be implemented as: X -= np.mean(X, axis = 0). With images specifically, for convenience it can be common to subtract a single value from all pixels (e.g. X -= np.mean(X)), or to do so separately across the three color channels.

**Normalization** refers to normalizing the data dimensions so that they are of approximately the same scale. There are two common ways of achieving this normalization. One is to divide each dimension by its standard deviation, once it has been zero-centered: (X /= np.std(X, axis = 0)). Another form of this preprocessing normalizes each dimension so that the min and max along the dimension is -1 and 1 respectively. It only makes sense to apply this preprocessing if you have a reason to believe that different input features have different scales (or units), but they should be of approximately equal importance to the learning algorithm. In case of images, the relative scales of pixels are already approximately equal (and in range from 0 to 255), so it is not strictly necessary to perform this additional preprocessing step.

Mean subtraction Balances the data around a point (Centering)
Centering fights vanishing and exploding gradients, while probably also increasing convergence speed and accuracy.

I would recommend you to go through the link. It explains these topics in much better detail